# Bitmap field taking focus on whole screen

Tags: blackberry, bitmap, focus

I have added 2 `BitmapFields`(left and right arrow) on one `HorizontalFieldManager`, but when I click anywhere on HFM, BitmapFields taking focus and shows that it is selected.

I want not to show focus anywhere until it doesn't click on `BitmapFields`.

Following is the code for it:

```
bmfBottomRight = new BitmapField(bmpBottomRightFocused, FOCUSABLE) {
                protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) {
                    int fieldIndex = getCurrentFieldIndex();
                    if (fieldIndex < (surveyList.size() - 1))
                        updateIncrField(fieldIndex);
                    return super.navigationClick(status, time);
                }
            };

            bmfBottomLeft.setPadding(5, 0, 5, ((Display.getWidth() - bmfBottomRight.getPreferredWidth()) >> 1) - bmfBottomRight.getPreferredWidth());
```

I am setting Padding for it..

Comment: Ok, I will take care of it.
I am also using navigation click to perform some action, such as changing label field on the screen.
My problem is not for `navigationClick()`.
My issue is that - it is getting focus for all `HorizontalFieldManager`. I want to limit focus on arrows only.

Comment: `navigationClick()` affects how focus is transferred between fields, so if you don't implement it correctly, your focus handling won't work right.  that's why I asked.

Comment: I am using navigationClick() as
`bmp = new BitmapField()
{
protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) {

    return false;
   };
}`

Comment: In your question, you show a **different** implementation of `navigationClick()`, so I'm not sure which one you're using.  If all you do is `return false;` in `navigationClick()`, then you are telling the OS that your `BitmapField` is never handling the click, and the click should be passed to another `Field` or `Manager` to handle.  That's only correct if your `BitmapField` is not clickable/focusable. Take a look at the [API documentation for navigationClick()](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Field.html#navigationClick%28int,%20int%29)

Comment: Thanks Nate, I have got the solution as I mentioned in my answer below.
Also, thanks for your help and efforts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have added null fields `new NullField(Field.NON_FOCUSABLE)`. And added two different null fields at left and right of `bitmap field`. SO I am able to getting the focus on bitmapfield, when only tapping on it.